# Does setTimeout function somehow work with iOS Shortcuts using Run JavaScript on Web Page?

Tags: javascript, ios, settimeout, delay, shortcut

I'm trying to create an iOS shortcut on my iPad using Run JavaScript on Web Page to configure a router when connected to its WiFi.
The functions work separately when I select a particular section of the router configuration web page before executing a shortcut. But what I need is changing the setup of the router by executing all the functions in one single script.
When I call 192.168.0.1 the first function would be for logging in, the next function for changing the network options, the next one for changing the security options etc. For this I apparently need setTimeout() to have time to select different pages in the menu. For some reason setTimeout() doesn't really work on iOS in Safari. It seems to be a known problem but I couldn't find any solutions or work arounds for the current iOS version yet.

I tried setTimeout(), setInterval() and exectuion of a function on condition like the following:

```
var starttime = 0;
var now = new Date().getTime();
if((now - starttime) > 2000) {...}
```

Here is a code snippet:

```
function defaultLogin(){
document.getElementByID('username').value = 'admin';
document.getElementByID('pcPassword').value = 'admin';
}

function clickBtn(){
document.getElementByID('loginBtn').click();
}

function changeLoginData{
window.frames['frame1'].contentDocument.documentElement.getElementsByClassName('T plus')[9].firstElementChildclick();

...
}

defaultLogin();
clickBtn();
setTimeout(changeLoginData, 1000);

completion();
```

I do not get any errors but the function changeLoginData() seems to be executed before logging in which is obviously pointless because i.e. the element ('T plus')[9] hasn't been loaded at that stage.

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance! Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `setTimeout()` is not a pausing operation. It's a queuing mechanism. Your callback will run after the current call stack is empty, `completion()` is going to run before `changeLoginData()`. If you need to hold `completion()` back until `changeLoginData()` is complete, put the call to `completion()` at the end of `changeLoginData()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Scott. When I put the call to completion() at the end of changeLoginData() I get the error "Run JavaScript on Web Page failed because the script took too long to call the completion handler." According to https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwjs9-act6rkAhUEqaQKHWtiA7gQFjACegQICxAH&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.apple.com%2Fguide%2Fshortcuts%2Fuse-the-run-javascript-on-webpage-action-apdb71a01d93%2Fios&usg=AOvVaw321YmCXuxn_JyODIdRtATw there are some time limitations for executing the script.